# Matrix transpose times itself

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We define A to be a matrix in $R^{m*n}$

1. Does $A^TA$ have any particular structure?
2. When is $A^TA$ invertible?

Comment: I know that the transpose of a matrix times itself is square and symmetric. Any help for the second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the properties of the matrix you are talking about are

- In my area of research (signal processing), this is referred to as the gram matrix. I believe, this is the standard name as well.
- It is a positive (semi) definite (PD) matrix. If you know about PD matrices, proving this is straight forward. The trick is this relation $x^Tx=||x||_2^2\geq 0$. Thus all results applicable to PD matrices are also applicable to the above matrix. (For eg: all eigenvalues are non-negative, cholesky decomposition and so on).
- Then, if $det(A^TA)\neq 0$, then columns of $A$ are linearly independent. Try to think about the converse.

Comment: Great help! thank you.

Comment: I believe the gram matrix is $A A^T$, not $A^T A$. These are equivalent if (and only if) the matrix is [normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2126827/matrix-a-multiply-a-transpose)

Comment: @ProQ, well, it will depend on how you define the data vectors, whether as column or row of $A$. The prevalent definition seems to be what I did. 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix