# Matrix A multiply A transpose

Tags: matrices, transpose

Suppose $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, and wondering when $A A^T$ equals $A^T A$? Only when $A$ is symmetric?

regards,
Lin

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158219/is-a-matrix-multiplied-with-its-transpose-something-special

Comment: Perhaps this may help answer your question?

Comment: @WaveX, nice reference and vote up!  I think as long as A is a normal matrix, it is fine, not necessarily to be orthogonal matrix, correct?

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure if being orthogonal is necessary or not. I've just started studying Linear Algebra this year.

Comment: @WaveX, your answer looks like a professor. Nice work and looking forward to talking more with you on math exchange. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symmetric matrices are not the only matrices that satisfy this property. There is a definition for the matrix that you describe:

If $A$ is a complex matrix that satisfies $A^{\ast}A=AA^{\ast}$, then we say A is a normal matrix. Note that $A^{\ast}$ represents $A$ adjoint, i.e. the complex conjugate transpose of $A$.

So if $A$ is just a real matrix and $A$ satisfies
$A^tA=AA^t$, then $A$ is a normal matrix, as the complex conjugate transpose of a real matrix is just the transpose of that matrix.

For example, a $2\times 2$ counterclockwise rotation matrix by an angle $\theta$ is given by
$B=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta&-\sin\theta \\
\sin\theta& \cos\theta
\end{bmatrix}$. Notice $B$ is not a symmetric matrix, but does satisfy $B^tB=BB^t$.

Comment: Thanks TASPlasma, vote up, could you elaborate a bit more what do you mean `adjoint` and `complex conjugate`? Do you mean the elements of matrix is complex number, not real number?

Comment: Yes I can. Often times, we consider matrices with complex numbers as entries instead of just purely real numbers. If $a+bi$ is a complex number, then the complex conjugate of $a+bi$ is $a-bi$. The adjoint of a matrix with complex entries, transposes the matrix, and also replaces every complex entry with their respective complex conjugate.
Note that if our matrix is strictly a real matrix (in other words only has real entries), then the adjoint of that matrix is exactly equal to the transpose of that matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the nice reply TASPlasma, mark your reply as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Matrices with that property are called normal matrices.

See [Normal Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix)

Comment: nice and vote up!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A \in M_{n,n}(\mathbb{R})$ then

$$AA^T = A^TA \iff A \textrm{ is normal}$$

Comment: Don't you mean $A$ is a normal matrix? An orthogonal matrix A is one that satisfies
$A^tA=AA^t=I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. Not all normal matrices are orthogonal matrices.

Comment: Not necessarily. $A$ is normal in this case, but it need not be orthogonal (the implication only goes from right to left).

Comment: You're right. I will correct it.

Comment: @MaciejCaputa, nice reply and vote up. But how orthogonal related here? I think as long as A is a normal matrix, it is fine, not necessarily to be orthogonal matrix, correct?

Comment: Yes, it is enough for $A$ to be normal matrix to satisfy the equation.

Conversely, every matrix satisfying this equation must be normal but doesn't have to be orthogonal

Comment: Thanks for the reply Maciej, vote up.