# Matrix times the transpose of itself, all inverse. Any interesting properties?

Tags: matrices, inverse

I was wondering if $(A A^T) ^{-1}$ had any interesting properties and if it could be simplified into a different form?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: The title talks about $(AA^T)^2$, the body of the question talks about $(AA^T)^{-1}$. Which is it?

Comment: @almagest fixed thanks

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/874429/339790

Answer (score 0):

This type of matrix is called the $ \ Gramian$ matrix. You can study it's properties on Wikipedia.

Comment: I had a look, I can't seem to recognise how this is a Gramian matrix.

Comment: Refer to http://mlwiki.org/index.php/Gram_Matrices . This website has a pretty good introduction to gram matrix and its properties.

Comment: It's the inverse of a Gramian, which is not quite what you wrote.